# Haskell: Higher Order function to use to group an increasing decreasing list

Tags: haskell

Given a list `[1,2,31,23,22,1,43]` Would like to use a higher order function to group elements `[[1,2,31], [23,22,1], [43]]` . increasing / decreasing list, where the elements initially the elements are in increasing order and then in decreasing order.

```
groupIncDec :: Ord a => [a] -> [[a]]
```

Each element in the output list `[[a]]` should be either all increasing or all decreasing, like in the example above, first element `[1,2,31]` is all increasing, second `[23,22,1]` all decreasing and because the there is a single element left and the previous state was all decreasing, `[43]` can be classified as all increasing.

Could not figure out if/how to use `groupBy` . Any hints would be appreciated.

Thanks.

[Edit: added some more description, which will hopefully clarify the question further.]

Comment: What does that function do exactly? I can't tell from that example alone.

Comment: seems like `groupIncDec` could wrap a pair of co-recursive `([[a]], [a]) -> ([[a]], [a])` functions, which call themselves while `x` is going in the same direction, call each other when `x` goes in the opposite direction, and base cases out when `xs` is `[]`.

Comment: You cannot use `groupBy` because it doesn't have memory, it can only look at two adjacent elements at a time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's another approach.  For the moment, let's assume that the list has no adjacent equal elements, like your example.  If the list `lst` is compared with its own tail, element-by-element:

```
> let lst = [1,2,31,23,22,1,43]
> let dir = zipWith compare lst (tail lst)
> dir
[LT,LT,GT,GT,GT,LT]
```

then `dir` represents whether adjacent elements are increasing or decreasing.  If we were to repeat the head of this list:

```
> let dir' = head dir : dir
> dir'
[LT,LT,LT,GT,GT,GT,LT]
```

then `dir'` corresponds to how the list `[1,2,31,23,22,1,43]` should be grouped.  By zipping `dir'` with `lst` and grouping by the `dir'` elements, we get:

```
> import Data.Function  -- for `on`
> let groups = groupBy ((==) `on` fst) (zip dir' lst)
> groups 
[[(LT,1),(LT,2),(LT,31)],[(GT,23),(GT,22),(GT,1)],[(LT,43)]]
```

which we can filter to:

```
> map (map snd) groups
[[1,2,31],[23,22,1],[43]]
```

So, putting this all together, we get a higher-order solution:

```
groupIncDec' :: Ord a => [a] -> [[a]]
groupIncDec' lst =
  let dir = zipWith compare lst (tail lst)
  in  map (map snd)
      $ groupBy ((==) `on` fst)
      $ zip (head dir : dir) lst
```

This doesn't work properly on lists with adjacent duplicate elements, but we can take such a list:

```
lst' = [1,2,31,31,23,22,22,1,43]
```

and group it:

```
group lst' = [[1],[2],[31,31],[23],[22,22],[1],[43]]
```

and then effectively apply the above algorithm before "ungrouping" it again to get the final result.  That looks like this:

```
groupIncDec :: Ord a => [a] -> [[a]]
groupIncDec xs =
  let ys = group xs
      dir = zipWith (comparing head) ys (tail ys)
  in  map (concatMap snd)
      $ groupBy ((==) `on` fst)
      $ zip (head dir : dir) ys
```

which works like so:

```
> groupIncDec [1,2,31,23,22,1,43]
[[1,2,31],[23,22,1],[43]]
> groupIncDec [1,2,31,31,23,22,22,1,43]
[[1,2,31,31],[23,22,22,1],[43]]
```

Answer (score 2):

`groupBy` is meant to group by **equality**, not a general binary relation. For example:

```
Prelude Data.List> groupBy (<) [1,3,2]
[[1,3,2]]
```

it is a span of first element `1` (as `1<3`, `1<2`).

---

I came up with a solution of `foldl`, but this is not a very clean solution.

```
groupIncDec :: Ord a => [a] -> [[a]]
groupIncDec = map reverse . reverse . foldl f []
  where f []                 x = [[x]]
        f ([y]:ys)           x = [x,y]:ys
        f (ys@(y1:y2:_):yss) x = if x < y1 && y1 < y2 || x > y1 && y1 > y2
                                 then (x:ys):yss
                                 else [x]:ys:yss
```

`f` is of type `[[a]] -> a -> [[a]]`, i.e. the accumulation part.

Because Haskell List is good at dealing the head element (with help of `:`), so the results are stored backward. Thus `map reverse . reverse` is needed.

---

1. http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:groupBy
2. http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:foldl